# Swift 2: Showing View Controller by UISwipeGestureRecognizer. How do I make the view controller follow my finger

Tags: ios, swift, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I am using `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` to show another view controller,

and I don't know how to make View Controller to follow my finger.

How do I do this?

The direction is from down to up, and if it is swiped, another View controller show up.

How do I make this View Controller to follow my finger?

Comment: You won't be able to do this using UISwipeGestureRecognizer. Per the docs: "A swipe is a discrete gesture, and thus the associated action message is sent ONLY ONCE per gesture." (Emphasis mine.) Try a UIPanGestureRecognizer, which gives you updates as your finger tracks.

Answer (score 0):

//------------right  swipe gestures in view--------------//

```
    let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("rightSwiped"))
    swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)
```

// Calling method :

```
   func rightSwiped()
    {
        self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }
```

You want to pushView Controller then use `UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left` in above code

Comment: Thank you. However, It will be great if you tell me this:  when we use UISwipeGestureRecognizer to show a view controller, and when we swipe it,

how do i make the view controller follow my finger?;

So basically i want the View controller to follow my finger when I swipe up.

How do I do this?